# GCMBaseIntentService onMessage method never called

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

i'm mostly new to android technologies. I had a project where GCM was working. Now I merged that project with other and GCM just stopped working...

My service is calling onRegistered method properly, but when I send a message to the phone nothing is happening.

Any ideas??
Here is GCMBaseIntentService.java

```
package com.example.truque;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "733836832755";

    private static final String TAG = "ACAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!!";

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super(PROJECT_ID);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCMIntentService init");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context ctx, String sError) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message Received");

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        sendGCMIntent(ctx, message);

    }


    private void sendGCMIntent(Context ctx, String message) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("gcm", message);

        ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;        
        CharSequence tickerText = "Leeme"; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
        Context con = ctx.getApplicationContext();     
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Mensaje recibido";  
        CharSequence contentText = message;      
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(con, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // and this
        int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        File f = new File("messages.txt");
        if(!f.exists()){
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput("messages.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);

                String c=getCanal(message);
                String n=getNick(message);
                String m=getMensaje(message);
                fos.write(("["+(new Date()).toString()+"]["+c+"]["+n+"] "+m).getBytes());
                fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
                fos.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    String getCanal(String m){
        return "Canal N";
    }
    String getNick(String m){
        return "Nick N";
    }
    String getMensaje(String m){
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send regId to your server
        Log.d(TAG, regId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send notification to your server to remove that regId
        Log.d("Unregistered ACAAAAA!!", regId);
    }

}
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.truque"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.truque.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.truque.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- receives GCM messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />

    <!-- wake the processor if a GCM message is received -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.AltaUsuario"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alta_usuario" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.Notis"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notis"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>        
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.truque" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service 
            android:name=".GCMIntentService" >
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.truque.PushReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you get a successful response from GCM server?

Comment: Yes I did. The server side is running well becouse on the unmerged app the message was recieved correctly.

Comment: Does your merged project have a different package= name in Android.manifest?

Comment: The name of the package where GCMBaseIntentService is located is com.example.truque. In the old project it was another package.

Comment: This might be the issue, check your API Access on Google API console to see if perhaps a new API key needs to be generated due to the change in package name.  If you're using a different signing certificate, this is definitely an issue

Comment: every thing looks good on the Console... what should I be looking at?

Comment: any ideas?? I desesperately need a solution...

Comment: @user2471107 Try to use your own BroadcastReceiver class, and see if the `onReceive` method is called (by writing to the log).

Comment: @user2471107 Try to use the code of the [current demo app](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/), which doesn't use the deprecated library.

Comment: the point might be you have to put your receiver and your service in main package of application .