# GCMBaseIntentService: method onMessage never called

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

i'm mostly new to android technologies. I had a project where GCM was working. Now I merged that project with other and GCM just stopped working...

My service is calling onRegistered method properly, but when I send a message to the phone nothing is happening.

Any ideas?? Here is GCMBaseIntentService.java

```
package com.example.truque;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "733836832755";

    private static final String TAG = "ACAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!!";

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super(PROJECT_ID);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCMIntentService init");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context ctx, String sError) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message Received");

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        sendGCMIntent(ctx, message);

    }


    private void sendGCMIntent(Context ctx, String message) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("gcm", message);

        ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;        
        CharSequence tickerText = "Leeme"; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
        Context con = ctx.getApplicationContext();     
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Mensaje recibido";  
        CharSequence contentText = message;      
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(con, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // and this
        int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        File f = new File("messages.txt");
        if(!f.exists()){
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput("messages.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);

                String c=getCanal(message);
                String n=getNick(message);
                String m=getMensaje(message);
                fos.write(("["+(new Date()).toString()+"]["+c+"]["+n+"] "+m).getBytes());
                fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
                fos.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    String getCanal(String m){
        return "Canal N";
    }
    String getNick(String m){
        return "Nick N";
    }
    String getMensaje(String m){
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send regId to your server
        Log.d(TAG, regId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send notification to your server to remove that regId
        Log.d("Unregistered ACAAAAA!!", regId);
    }

}
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.truque"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.truque.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.truque.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- receives GCM messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />

    <!-- wake the processor if a GCM message is received -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.AltaUsuario"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alta_usuario" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.truque.Notis"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notis"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>        
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.truque" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service 
            android:name=".GCMIntentService" >
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.truque.PushReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCMBaseIntentService onMessage method never called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712635/gcmbaseintentservice-onmessage-method-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make sure that service class put in your main pakage. Today I got the mistake that I moved it another package. and also you need to check if your device token is saved in server to get any push.
and also check those codes if it works or not

```
@Override protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // send regId to your server
    Log.d(TAG, regId);
```